# is there any way to inject all implementers (JSF Beans) of an interface in a Service managed by Spring?

Tags: java, jsf, interface, javabeans

I have this interface

```java
public interface DataHandler {
    void getData();
    
    String getControllerPrefix();
}
```

And it is being implemented in different controllers like the following

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class MyController implements DataHandler{
       //some code
}
```

That I want to do is getting all controllers that implement that interface injecting them in an attribute of my business layer. But is not working due to I'm trying to inject JSF beans (MyControllers) in a bean managed by spring (Business)

```java
@Service
public class Business {
    @Any
    private final Instance<DataHandler> dataHandlers;

    public void getData(String controllerPrefix) {
        //logic to get the right controller and its data
    }
```

I've been using the following method to get JSF beans and use them out of its own context

```java
public static <T> T getBeanFromFacesCtx(String beanQualifier, Class<T> clazz) {
        FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Application app = ctx.getApplication();
        T bean = app.evaluateExpressionGet(ctx, beanQualifier, clazz);
        return Optional.ofNullable(bean)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UnsupportedOperationException("It was not possible to return the Bean " + beanQualifier));
    }
```

However this time I'm looking for a best way to get it.
Is there any way to achieve that thing?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to obtain JSF beans outside the JSF context in so far as it being in "servlet code" not inside page code where the configuration and call of a bean is implicit.

**Just a reminder, JSF beans only have data context or good practice use with some form of "binding" to an element value!
Or it is absurd to be processing using JSF and it's one foot after the other thread sequence that is only manipulable using "phases".
What is the packaging and hierarchy of the classes wanted? Are they in JSF (the classes or interfaces extended) .**

**public void getData method should be inside class MyController because it implements the actual code for getData !
getHandler would be a better name , getData should at least obtain the result but more sensibly the data input for the handler !**

**getApplication()** I think you are trying to get e.g. the ApplicationContextFacade that is normally (ULTIMATELY) the Servlet context or PageContext and in JSF the FacesContext.
"JSF Runtime is on an isolated sub thread" , so accessing the aka context of the app is "momentary" at time of call from FacesContext through the thread to the ApplicationContext.

QUOTE from one of my docs...

Unfortunately, to use a managed bean in JSF would be around three different steps and an Enum of constants or a Collection of urls
But that does not make output more flexible at in page coding either for a graphic image.
Neither does that allow server connection utilization and conservation.
The following it can be reduced to with this API and faces , simple enough "in a managed bean" for JSF.
For a faces app , these are good to have handy running in Oracle 1.8.0_202
// jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-2.0.0.jar jakarta.inject-api-2.0.0.jar jakarta.annotation-api-62.jar

The following can be obtained in a jakarta faces managed bean using jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar with the com.sun WebConfiguration class
This is supplied for backward compatibility only to use the com.sun classes.

```
public String makeImg(String umber){
// jakarta.faces-3.0.0-RC5.jar
WebConfiguration wbc = WebConfiguration.getInstance();
ServletContext appconxt = wbc.getServletContext();
WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat = (WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj)appconxt.getAttribute("DataStoreObj");
RamStringB64 b64obj = dat.getRAMStringB64Store();
imagedata = (b64obj.getRAMstringB64((int)new Integer(umber).intValue()));
return imagedata;
}
```

In either jakarta.faces or javax.faces now , only the following is suppiled and must be cast to jakarta.servlet.ServletContext or javax.servlet.ServletContext respectively
[ if the server app is not a Portlet ].

```
public String makeImg(String umber){
//jakarta.faces-3.0.0.jar
// WARNING FROM HERE TO
jakarta.servlet.ServletContext appconxt = (jakarta.servlet.ServletContext)(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()).getExternalContext().getContext();
WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj dat = (WebAppToolRAMDataServingObj)appconxt.getAttribute("DataStoreObj");
RamStringB64 b64obj = dat.getRAMStringB64Store();
// HERE MUST BE CALLED
// EACH SINGLE TIME WARNING DO NOT ATTEMPT GLOBAL SETUP WARNING
base64string = (b64obj.getRAMstringB64((int)new Integer(umber).intValue()));
return base64string;
}
```

**Also, this appears to be what you are doing in some way, it is possible to write a custom DataContentHandler for a specific MIME type of it fulfills all required methods for a DataHandler
javax.activation Interface DataContentHandler**